# Android Studio include all aar files in a directory

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm writing a build system for a framework which can be extended via plugins by users (developers). My problem is that I can't include all aar files with a mask. For example I can include all jar files like this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

But if I include all aar files like this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
```

I get an error:

```
Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle: /path/to/file.aar
```

However it is possible to include each file separately like this:

```
compile (name:'myfile', ext:'aar')
```

As a workaround, during the build, I will need to list the files in 'libs' directory, insert all the libraries manually into my build.gradle and keep it in sync (or rewrite each time). it's a hackish way of doing it and thus I wonder if there is a better way of doing it. Maybe there is a gradle script which can do it automatically or some gradle beta which supports this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
```

Comment: You can find more information about advanced dependency management with Gradle in my question and answer here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31662781/746347

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First add `flatDir` repository:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Then after `dependencies` section add:

```
fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.aar')
        .each { File file ->
    dependencies.add("compile", [
        name: file.name.lastIndexOf('.').with { it != -1 ? file.name[0..<it] : file.name }, 
        ext: 'aar'
    ])
}
```

Comment: How to add the transitive = true , to this script?

Comment: @JavierVargas Dependency transitivity makes sense when there is some dependency resolver that builds dependency tree. But this script only adds `aar` library files and they do not have information (`pom.xml`) about dependencies so transitivity does not make sense in this case. You can read more in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35311889/746347

Comment: Getting `Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported. Cannot handle .aar` warnings, so it didn't work, I am on gradle 2.13.

Comment: @Bob I tested with Gradle 2.13. It works. That warning is given when you try to add aar dependencies like `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs/compile', include: '**/*.aar')`. Instead of that you should programmatically iterate over all aar files and add dependencies as `compile(name:'<name of aar file without extension>', ext: 'aar')`. And my answer does this. Just add code snippet from my answer after `dependencies` section.

Answer (score 3):

You can put your aar files in a folder.
You have to define this folder inside the `repositories` block. Of course you can use the libs folder

Something like:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'myAarFolder'
    }
}
```

Then you can use in your dependencies something like:

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'nameOfYourAARFile', ext:'aar')
}
```

As I know there is no way to incluse all aars with a wildcard as *.

Answer (score 3):

I know this answer is late to the game, but for others coming here, I have managed it without using the repository.flatDir.
Just add the fileTree() AFTER the dependencies section

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.aar')
    .each { File file ->
dependencies.add("compile", files( 'libs/'+file.name ))
}
```

Comment: Not work for me. Get error `Only Jar-type local dependencies are supported`.
Which android gradle build plugin were you using?

Comment: This is the same solution from the accepted answer that was published only three years before...